# Proximity Sensor Gestures

Tags: android, gestures, proximity

I tried googling around for a solution but couldn't find one. There's tons of app out there that use the proximity sensor (and presumably the ambient light sensor) to detect gestures. How do they do this? I am currently able to get sensor values from the proximity sensor but how would I create logic that detects the actual waving gesture that people use on their device? Could someone point me in the correct direction to get myself going on this? Thanks!

Comment: maybe the front Camera is used to recognize gestures like hand waving

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) class (code example in link) to listen for changes registered by the proximity sensor (`Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY`).  But as far as I know it only recognizes "near" and "far", it is not the light sensor (`Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT`), it really only has those two very basic states.

Comment: I know how to use the SensorManager class with TYPE_PROXIMITY, but how do I use it to detect specific gestures? Wave Control and other apps out there do this.

Comment: I have never used Wave Control, so I have no idea what type of gestures it recognizes. My point is that you can only use very basic gestures. For instance a slow, close fingered wave might have the pattern "far", "near" for one second, "far".  While a slow, open fingered wave would be "far", "near" for quarter of a second (1/4s), "far" 1/4s, "near" 1/4s, "far" 1/4s, "near" 1/4s, "far" 1/4s, "near" 1/4s, "far". As far as the light sensor, I almost had to touch the phone to register a change (less than a centimeter)... which seem impractical to me. I'd rather touch the phone.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for explaining the logic! And yes, the light sensor is useless... I've been playing around with it for the past few days and its done nothing. Unfortunately, I really don't understand how I would implement the "far" "near" "far" logic for the proximity sensor in code. So far, my app works with ANY gesture over the proximity sensor but I need to limit it to a wave gesture only. I know I need to do this in the "onSensorChanged" method, but how would I keep track of the times? Would I use the event.timeStamp() method? Thanks again for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the proximity sensor can report only far/near sates the only way to make a decision about waves is to calculate time interval between far-near states. Fast wave - short interval, slow - long.